# JSP Issue displaying a Java double

Tags: jsp, double

I'm having trouble storing a double field that gets accepted by the end User.
If the user enters 100.00 the value appears to loose a decimal place and gets displayed as 100.0 
The JSP I'm using for accepting input from the user looks like:

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" groupingUsed="false" maxFractionDigits="2" value="${payment.netPayment}" var="fmtNetPayment"/>
    <form:input path="netPayment" id="netPayment" value="${fmtNetPayment}" cssErrorClass="error"/>
        <form:errors path="netPayment">
            <span class="errorBox">
            <span class="errorArrow"></span> 
            <span class="errorMsg"><form:errors path="netPayment"/></span>
            </span>
    </form:errors>
```

When I loop through my items on a summary page using the following code, the amount appears as 100.0 when it should be displaying two decimal places as 100.00

```
<div>
  <span class="netPayment"></span>
  <c:out value="${payment.netPayment}"/>                                                  
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How is 100.00 different from 100.0? A double is a number, not a String.

Comment: I always need to display two decimal places

Comment: The answer is in the question: use `<fmt:formatNumber>` instead of displaying the double value directly.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried using <fmt:formatNumber> within the c:out tag but couldn't get it working. Have you an example I can see?

Answer (score 2):

formats a number, and sends it to the JSP writer (i.e. displays it), unless you use the var attribute, in which case it stored the formatted number in a page attribute. So you just need

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${payment.netPayment}" type="number" groupingUsed="false" maxFractionDigits="2" />
```

Note that using double to represent amounts of money is a bad idea. You should prefer BigDecimal.